# Can I keep a backup ssd plugged into a computer?

Tags: ssd, backup, storage

I have an SSD used for backing up data, however, SSD's are known to lose data after a certain amount of time. I was wondering if there is any danger to leaving the SSD plugged into a usb port at the back of my computer.

Comment: 'SSD's are known to lose data after a certain amount of time' - by whom? I think that is just wrong information.

Comment: So I think you may have heard of HDDs losing data over time. Here is a link.https://superuser.com/questions/284427/how-much-time-until-an-unused-hard-drive-loses-its-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there is no danger. Older cheaper SSDS from the first few generations had low read/write limits number in the hundreds of terabytes. You wont be using this drive often except to backup so no harm will be caused.

**EDIT**
Read this [link:here](https://techreport.com/review/27909/the-ssd-endurance-experiment-theyre-all-dead) it talks a lot about SSD endurance and things like that. However most SSDs from what I can gather only start to show wear once they transferred 200TBs of information a year.

> Clear evidence of flash wear appeared after 200TB of writes, when the Samsung 840 Series started logging reallocated sectors >

The article goes onto state.

> The 840 Series didn't encounter actual problems until 300TB, when it failed a hash check during the setup for an unpowered data retention test.

However:

> After receiving a black mark on its permanent record, the 840 Series sailed smoothly up to 800TB. But it suffered another spate of uncorrectable errors on the way to 900TB, and it died without warning before reaching a petabyte.

**2n EDIT**

I have never read anywhere that SSDs loose data overtime. I would like to see your source on the matter.

**3rd EDIT**
Regarding data degrading over time... It originally spawned from this presentation slide: [image] and the following news article.

> “The standards body for the microelectronics industry has found that Solid State Drives (SSD) can start to lose their data and become corrupted if they are left without power for as little as a week,” said the International Business Times, one of the first to run a story on the blog post. From there, the Internet seemed to amplify as fact that an SSD left unplugged would lose data—all citing Cox’s JEDEC presentation.

The following [article](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2925173/debunked-your-ssd-wont-lose-data-if-left-unplugged-after-all.html) debunks the myths behind data lose due to heat/temperature change.

> The original presentation dates back to when Cox chaired a committee for JEDEC, the industry group that blesses memory specs. It was intended to help data center and enterprise customers understand what could happen to an SSD—but only after it had reached the end of its useful life span and was then stored at abnormal temperatures. It’s not intended to be applied to an SSD in the prime of its life in either an enterprise or a consumer setting.

Comment: Ok I'm probably wrong on the whole losing data thing. Thanks. Continuously turning on and off my computer (like once or twice daily) wont degrade the lifetime either right?

Comment: @Xertz, the debunked information discussed at the end of the answer was for SSDs in a powered off state, not powered on.  The concern you are likely most familiar with has to do with data write cycles.  Turning power to the SSD on and off has no effect on its life.  Note, though that some USB ports might keep the SSD powered on even when the computer is off.  That won't affect the SSD, but if it is a laptop that is unplugged and it sits like that for a long time, you could run the battery charge down.

Comment: Hey @Xertz if you could vote my answer as the solution ^_^ others would find this post more for information and you wont get other wrong answers.

Comment: @bcm27 I do believe I did